# How to compute $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^{G(x)} \arctan(s+2s^2) ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, trigonometry, definite-integrals

> Suppose $g$ is a function that has its derivatives everywhere and $G(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt$. How to compute $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^{G(x)} \arctan(s+2s^2) ds$?

To start this question, we need to integrate $\arctan(s+2s^2)$ but how do you do that?

Then, what do we do with the $\int_0^{G(x)}$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Fundamental theorem of calculus? There are two versions of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

> You can use L'hopital's rule twice